# Line height in an E-Mail (HTML) created with Excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have the following VBA Code to create an E-Mail within an Excel spreadsheet:

```
Sub Test_EMail()
    If ExitAll = False Then
        Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
        Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OMail
            .Display
            End With
            signature = OMail.HTMLbody
            With OMail
            .To = "test@test.de"
            .Subject = "test"
            .HTMLbody = "<p> Hello </p>" _
            & vbCr & "<p> I want to have a specific line hight because this </p>" _
            & vbCr & "<p> line height is too much space </p>" _
            & vbCr & "<p> How I can decrease this line height? </p>"
            End With
        Set OMail = Nothing
        Set OApp = Nothing
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

The code itself works perfectly. However, when I see the E-Mail there is a big line height between the three sentences written with HTML.

If I try to go with this:

```
& vbCr & <p style="line-height: 50%">I want to have a specific line hight because this</p>
```

it also does not work which might be due to the mixing of a VBA and HTML Code.

Do you have any idea how I can change the line height in the E-Mail within the VBA code?

Comment: Try taking out the `vbCr` at each point because I believe the `<p>` will be sufficient in making sure you have the line break you want.

Comment: I deleted the vbCr but the issue remains the same. I also tried to to go with the style code but did not work either.

Comment: I guess you could try the other way around: delete the `<p>` tags and keep the `vbCr`, although I'm more used to seeing `vbCrLf`.

Comment: If I delete the <p> then there is alos no line break anymore and everything appears in the same line. However, I want to have a line break but with a lower line height.

Comment: OK. Maybe take out both `vbCr` and the `<p>` tags and add `<br>` tags instead.

Comment: We getting closer to the solution. When I use <br> instead of <p> there is no space between the lines. However, I want to have a space between the headline "Hello" and the first sentence. Therefore, I tried to go with this: "<p> Hello </p><br>I want to have a specific line height because this</br> Now there is a huge space between "Hello" and the first sentence. How I can get rid of this huge space?

Comment: How about this: `Hello <br><br>`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an HTML format email, the HTML opening and closing tags must also be inserted.

```
Dim body_ As String
    body_= "<p> Hello </p>" _
         & "<p> I want to have a specific line hight because this </p>" _
         & "<p> line height is too much space </p>" _
         & "<p> How I can decrease this line height? </p>"

.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = "<html><head></head><body>" & body_ & "</body></html>"
```