# HTMLBody Vs Body in VBA - Formatting Issues with Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that houses several macros, one takes a message body that has been entered into a specific cell (this changes every quarter based on what the business wants) and uses it as the email body that is generated by the macro.  The body of the email is pre-formatted when entered into this cell and retains that formatting when I use the regular body in VBA but loses its formatting when I change it to HTMLBody.  They recently changed the email message to include hyperlinks.  Unfortunately, if I try to make the hyperlinks look correct, it appears I need HTMLBody but then I lose the formatting of my message.

```
   OriginalText = HF.Sheets("Email_Setups").Range("B9").Value


   Link = "<a href=""" & "http://mylink.com" & """>Open Requests</a>"
   CorrectedText = Replace(OriginalText, "Open Requests", Link)



                'Create a new email item
        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        'From
        'To
        'objMail.To = Sheet1.Range("A" & lCounter).Value
        'Cc
        'objMail.CC = Sheet1.Range("B" & lCounter).Value
        'Subject
        objMail.Subject = HF.Sheets("Email_Setups").Range("A9").Value & " " & Tar_Num
        'Email Body
        objMail.HTMLBody = CorrectedText
```

With this using the HTMLBody, the formatting from the original cell text is lost.  Is there a way to retain it without having to enter the whole message body in HTML code (since it changes every time and needs to be something the business can do without me coding it) and still get the desired result of the hyperlink?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202033/line-height-in-an-e-mail-html-created-with-excel-vba/44203084#44203084

Comment: Thanks Kostas, this link appears to show the message being entered in HTML format via code, rather than just being taken from a cell.  Am I missing how it's converted?